# Jquery Scroll Loading All The Rows At Once And Should Only Load 5 At A Time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using the following script to load more, 5 rows at a time from the database, on scroll. All the rows are loading at once on scroll after the initial loads correctly. In realtime, the first 5 load. Then on scroll the last 14 load at once. Like it rushes to the end instead of incrementally loading 5 at a time. I use the same code for a load more button and it works fine. Same PHP file for both. No issue with that. Can anyone see why all the rows are being loaded on scroll instead of 5 at a time.

```
<script>
    //SET NUMBER OF ROWS TO DISPLAY AT A TIME
    rowsPerPage = 5;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // GETTING DATA FROM FUNCTION BELOW
        getData();

        window.onscroll = function() {

            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#load-container').offset().top + $('#load-container').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {

                $('#load-more').html('Loading...');

                var rowID = Number($("#row-id").val());
                var allCount = Number($("#count").val());

                rowID += rowsPerPage;

                if (rowID <= allCount) {

                    $("#row-id").val(rowID);

                    getData();

                } else {

                    $('#load-more').html('End Of Data');
                    //$('#load-more').html('');
                }

            }
        }

        /* REQUEST DATA */
        function getData() {
            var rowID = $("#row-id").val();
            var allCount = $("#count").val();
            $('#load-more').html('Loading...');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'promotions/newest-load-scroll-data-invalid.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    rowID: rowID,
                    rowsPerPage: rowsPerPage
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        loadData(response)
                    }, 1000);
                },
            });
        }

        /* LOAD DATA TO PAGE */

        function loadData(data) {
            var dataCount = data.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    var allCount = data[i]['allcount'];
                    $("#count").val(allCount);
                } else {
                    var promoID = data[i]['promoid'];
                    var promoNameNewest = data[i]['promoname'];
                    var promoNameNewestVideo = data[i]['promoname'];
                    var promoRefNum = data[i]['promorefnum'];
                    var promoType = data[i]['promotype'];
                    var theBanner = data[i]['thebanner'];
                    var email = data[i]['email'];
                    var customerType = data[i]['customerType'];

                    if (email == "") {

                        if (promoType == "Banner") {
                            $('#load-container').append('<div class="row-center-center padding-top-5 padding-bottom-2"><div>' + promoNameNewest + '</div></div>');
                            $('#load-container').append('<div><div class="wrap-content"><img class="mobile-banner-scale" id="visitor-banner-click" src=' + theBanner + '></div></div>');
                        }

                        if (promoType == "Video Banner") {
                            $('#load-container').append('<div class="row-center-center padding-top-5 padding-bottom-2"><div>' + promoNameNewestVideo + '</div></div>');
                            $('#load-container').append('<div><video class="mobile-video-size" id="visitor-banner-click" src=' + theBanner + ' autoplay muted loop></video></div>');
                        }

                    }

                    if (customerType == "p") {

                        if (promoType == "Banner") {
                            $('#load-container').append('<div class="row-center-center padding-top-5 padding-bottom-2"><div>' + promoNameNewest + '</div></div>');
                            $('#load-container').append('<div><div class="wrap-content"><img class="mobile-banner-scale" id="advertiser-banner-click" src=' + theBanner + '></div></div>');
                        }

                        if (promoType == "Video Banner") {
                            $('#load-container').append('<div class="row-center-center padding-top-5 padding-bottom-2"><div>' + promoNameNewestVideo + '</div></div>');
                            $('#load-container').append('<div><video class="mobile-video-size" id="advertiser-banner-click" src=' + theBanner + ' autoplay muted loop></video></div>');
                        }

                    }

                }

                $('#load-more').html('Loading...');
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: So, here's something fun for you to do.  As the first thing you do in your `onscroll` method, put `console.log('hey there')`, and then go to your page, open the developer tools and go to your console and then start scrolling.  See if you see anything interesting.

Comment: Fun indeed. I get one hundred results of hey there and if scroll like a madman and up and down the console goes nuts with what would end up being a million after a while. What's the deal lol?

Comment: The point is that while it appears to the user that they scrolled once, the scroll event is fired **a ton**, pretty much for every pixel change or some where along those lines.  So, if a ton of scroll events fire, and you are doing `rowID += rowsPerPage` every time, I'd imagine that's probably an issue.

Comment: Makes sense. I can't see how to fix that. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to utilize flags to make it work right with a couple other small changes. Appreciate the input, Taplar.